# XML update attributes: add characters at the end and fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to update the attributes of a xml. My problem is that when I update and later I read my xml I have an exception. I was looking for the problem and I don't know how but at the end of xml appears the last character of my general close tag. Sometimes the three or two characters last or only the character `>`. This problem don't occur always. Sometimes in the second time, others in fourth time, other in tenth times... I put a snippet bellow. thanks so much and sorry for my English.

PD: I don't use Linq

My XML

```
// At the end of xml file appears this fragment
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYPRINCIPALTAG>
    <TAG DATE="01/01/01"></TAG>
</MYPRINCIPALTAG>AG>
```

More code ;-)

```
// Read XML
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream (path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (fs);
while (reader.Read ()) {
switch (reader.NodeType) {
   case XmlNodeType.Element:
      switch (reader.Name) {
        case 'TAG':
            string pubdate = reader.GetAttribute (0);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
fs.Close(); 

public static XmlNode OpenXmlNode(string path, ref System.IO.FileStream fs, ref XmlDocument doc) {
     fs = new System.IO.FileStream (path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
     doc = new XmlDocument ();
     doc.Load (fs);
     fs.Flush ();
     fs.Close ();
     return doc.DocumentElement;
}

public static void CloseXmlNode(string path, ref System.IO.FileStream fs, ref XmlDocument doc) {
    fs = new System.IO.FileStream (path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    doc.Save (fs);
    fs.Flush ();
    fs.Close ();
}

 public static Boolean UpdateXML(string path, string id_tag) {
     try {
        System.IO.FileStream fs = null;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
        XmlNode element = OpenXmlNode (path, ref fs, ref doc);
        // Change Date
        element.ChildNodes[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem ("date").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString ("dd/MM/yy");
        for (int count = 1; count < doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count; count++) {
           if ((doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[count].Attributes.GetNamedItem ("ID").Value).Equals (id_tag)) {
              for (int i = 0; i < doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[count].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++) {
                doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[count].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i].Attributes.GetNamedItem ("STATE").Value = "ok";
              }
              break;
           }
        }
        CloseXmlNode (path, ref fs, ref doc);
        return true;
     } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: how your file exactly looks before editing?
Also let us see your full code

Comment: I have a lot of code. ;-) Up, I put the method that update the xml. In another method, I read the xml but I used the code that suggest in microsoft. For this reason I don't put that code. My XML before is: 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYPRINCIPALTAG>
    <TAG DATE="01/01/01"></TAG>
</MYPRINCIPALTAG>

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a fs.flush(); before fs.Close();
Like this

```
doc.Save(fs);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

Better still.  The way that you have written your code (with static functions), you don't seem to be benefitting from using filestreams (IMO).  I would change the functions OpenXmlNode() and CloseXmlNode() as follows:

```
public static XmlNode OpenXmlNode(string path, ref XmlDocument doc) 
{
     doc = new XmlDocument (); 
     doc.Load (path); 
     return doc.DocumentElement; 
} 
public static void CloseXmlNode(string path, ref XmlDocument doc) 
{ 
    doc.Save (path); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but Don't work. I'm thinking to manipulate the file if it have this problem. Namely, open the file, to go to the last line of my document and delete the characters that disturbe my peace. ;-) What do you think?

Comment: I don't think so that that could be better idea.It may reoccur if you are initializing some different values.
We need more detail about your code.
IT is actually versy simple thing

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I put more code above. For the time being, I put code in Read Method, because I need that work, you know. This is my fake code ;-), this works! : `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (path);
         if (!lines[lines.Length - 1].Equals ("</MYPRINCIPALTAG>")) {
            lines[lines.Length - 1] = "</MYPRINCIPALTAG>";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines (path, lines);
         }
         System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream (path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);...`

Comment: By opening the file for read/write, it could be leaving debris in the file (from the previous contents).  Have you tried opening the file for write (overwrite) when doing your output?

Comment: Better still, it might be easier to use the single-call XmlDocument.Save(filename) and skip the streams all together.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't understand you when you say single-call. Do you mean, I delete the code of FileStream? I looked for information in internet and I found that for to modify a xml file in several pages I need this code. Is that it?

Comment: The way that you have written this class, with static functions, you don't really get any benefit from using filestreams (IMO). I would rewrite the OpenXmlNode() and CloseXmlNode functions like this: public static XmlNode OpenXmlNode(string path, ref XmlDocument doc) { doc = new XmlDocument (); doc.Load (path); return doc.DocumentElement; } public static void CloseXmlNode(string path, ref XmlDocument doc) { doc.Save (path); } //Sorry, the comments don't format code very well.  I posted the code up above as an edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This Works!!! I'm doing test yet but it looks good. Thanks again, you save me ;-)